# $(3^{34})/55$ find out the reminder

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic, chinese-remainder-theorem

> $\cfrac{(3^{34})}{55}$ find out the reminder

**My Approach**

$3^1$ mod $55$=$3$

$3^2$ mod $55$=$9$

$3^3$ mod $55$=$7$

$3^4$ mod $55$=$6$

and the pattern repeats ..

So,I did $3$^$4$.$8$ +$2$=$3^2$=9 mod $55$=$9$.

> Can anyone guide me how to solve the problem?Pleae correct me if I am wrong?

Comment: Note that $3^3 = 27 \not\equiv 7 \mod 55$. Other than that I think you should also prove that this pattern repeats, if you want to use this approach, perhaps it will change completely right after the last step you observed?

Answer (score 1):

The Chinese remainder theorem says that we can focus on $\mod{11}$ and $\mod 5$, and stitch together the answers afterwards. Since $5$ and $11$ are prime, we can exploit Fermat's little theorem.

Modulo $5$: Fermat's little theorem gives $3^4\equiv 1$. This implies $3^{32} = 3^{4\cdot 8}\equiv 1$, and therefore $3^{34}\equiv 4\equiv -1\pmod 5$ (i will use whichever seems most handy later).

Modulo $11$: Fermat's little theorem gives $3^{10}\equiv 1$, which implies $3^{30}= 3^{10\cdot 3}\equiv 1$. This gives $3^{34} \equiv 3^4 = 81\equiv 4\pmod{11}$.

Now that that's over with, it's time to use the Chinese remainder theorem to stitch these two together to an answer modulo $55$. But we see tha both modulo $5$ and modulo $11$, $3^{34}\equiv 4$, which makes the job simple: It's still $4\!\!\!\mod{55}$.

Answer (score 0):

$55=5\cdot11$

$3^2\equiv-1\pmod5\implies3^{34}=(3^2)^{17}\equiv(-1)^{17}$

$\implies3^{34}\equiv-1\pmod5\equiv4\  \ \   \  (1)$

As $(3,11)=1,3^{10}\equiv1\pmod{11}$ and $34\equiv4\pmod{10}$

$\implies3^{34}\equiv3^4\pmod{11}\equiv4\  \ \   \  (2)$

Apply CRT on $(1),(2)$

Otherwise by observation $3^{34}\equiv4\pmod{11\cdot5}$ as $(11,5)=1$

Answer (score 0):

Note that last term of $3^4$ is 1 so  applying  for $3^{17}$ last digit is 3 so the remainder when divided by 55 is 53 so can you do for 34 using the patterns you have applied for first few powers. Hint $mod(11.5)$ so in general (11,5) has common divisor 1

Answer (score 0):

we calculate $3^{30}\equiv 34\mod 55$ and $3^4\equiv 26  \mod 55$ thus we get
$$3^{34}\equiv 4  \mod 55$$

Answer (score 0):

Using the CRT, as in other answers, is way better than this: but, for the fun of it...

$3$ is prime to $55$, and $\phi(55) = 10 \cdot 4 = 40$. So 
$ 3^{40} \equiv 1 \pmod{55}$, so $$3^{34} \cdot 3^6 \equiv 1.$$ On the other hand, $$2\cdot 3^3 = 54 \equiv -1.$$
Squaring the previous line and comparing with the line before, one gets $3^{34}\equiv 4$.